# Dealing with negative values in log scale

Tags: matlab, plot, standard-deviation

I'm plotting a line graph in MatLab with standard deviation using log scale:

```
fig = figure;
errorbar(mean(samples),sqrt(var(samples)));
ax = get(fig,'CurrentAxes');
set(ax,'YScale','log');
```

However, in some samples, the lower error bar is below 0. For example, given samples `s=[11.0147 80.2365 11.6116 11.1837 9.9091]`, then `mean=24.7911` and `std=31.0013`, which makes the lower error bar be at `-6.2101`. Since log scale ignores negative values, the error bars look really weird.

How do I calculate asymmetric error bars? I though of maybe calculating `std` for all values `>=mean` and for all values `<=mean`, so that I have different upper and lower error bars. Is this a valid approach?

Comment: The real question is why are you using a log-scale to plot something that could be negative?  If all of the samples are guaranteed to be positive, then you really shouldn't be plotting error bars this way as if the underlying distribution were Gaussian.  (That is the assumption that you are making by plotting error bars 1 standard deviation either side of the mean).  You may be better thinking about error bars in terms of quartiles/ranges.  Of course, if the values *can* be negative, then you may also get a negative mean, in which case you shouldn't be using a log scale at all!

Comment: All values are positive, but they don't look well with linear scale. They go from 1e5 to 1e-1 in about 100 samples and then they go to 1e-5 in 700 samples. It makes the graph quite confusing, since there are two other plots in it.

Comment: OK - you definitely don't want to use error bars in the "Gaussian" sense since your underlying probability distribution is not even symmetric.  So, unless you know (or can determine) the probability distribution, then you should make your error bars based on some form of quartile.  You could, for example, use the 5% and 95% points (5% of the samples below the lower error bar, and 5% above the upper error bar).  It means that they will be unequal in size, but this better reflects your data.  Don't try to use the standard deviation as it only makes sense for Gaussian distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to produce 5% and 95% error bars, the simplest thing to do is sort the underlying data.  So, say you have a set of samples corresponding to a particular parameter, and they are recorded in a matrix, samples, where one row represents your experimental values for one value of the parameter, x.  Then this code would give you upper and lower values quite readily:

```
ascending=sort(samples,2);
lower_error_bar=ascending(:,round(size(ascending,2)*0.05));
mean=mean(samples,2);
median=ascending(:,round(size(ascending,2)*0.5));
upper_error_bar=ascending(:,round(size(ascending,2)*0.95));
```

I hope this helps!